# How can I make a connection in web api C# with MSSQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm making a chat application in web api, using ASP.NET, SignalR in VS code. My database is MSSQL and i have a problem with the connection. I'm a little bit confused, because I used a MySQL connection like in this code, because i thought, that it will work, but I had a lots error with this connection:

```
public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
        {
            MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;
            string myConnectionString;

            myConnectionString = "server=localhost;uid=sa;" +
                "pwd=123456789;database=DBChatApp";

            try
            {
                conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
                conn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"user={user}, message={message}");
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        }
    }
```

I need to make the connection in MSSQL and put the users and the messages into a table. I didn't find any article it, only with the MySQL.

Comment: You need to use `SqlConnection` from `System.Data.SqlClient`

Comment: You are using a connection object of type MySqlConnection, you should be using SqlConnection for sql server

Comment: thank you very much, its working